# Migrate from Oracle JDK to OpenJDK

Tags: java, migrate

Migrate from Oracle JDK to OpenJDK.

My services installed OracleJDK package version:

1.

> java version "1.6.0_45" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.6.0_45-b06) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

2.

> java version "1.8.0_151" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_151-b12) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

3.

> java version "1.7.0_67" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.7.0_67-b01) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

What are OpenJDK versions same with each my OracleJDK version? 
Please help me

Comment: Why do you need to?

Comment: @Michael Free update of Oracle JDK (formerly Sun JDK) that is widely used in app, service and solution development/operations ends in January '19. 
Accordingly, it cannot be used for business, commercial or operational purposes without a commercial license.

Comment: But, for example, Java 6 is already out of public support for both the OpenJDK and the Oracle JDK. Oracle JDK 7 has been out of public support for ages. Why are you deciding this now? You can continue to use all 3 for free, just as you always could, but you will not receive public support - you need to pay.

Comment: Hi @Michael For public update versions that use a specific commercial API, commercial licensing agreements are also required for enterprise operations and services (Oracle BCL licenses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is going to help, but the OpenJDK version numbers match the Oracle JDK version numbers.

The problems are:

- Where do you find a downloadable build of OpenJDK for a particular version and hardware platform.
- (For Linux and similar) how do you map the OpenJDK version to a package or set of packages for your preferred distro.

Certainly, you are unlikely to find Java 6 or Java 7 packages for recent releases of Linux in the standard package repo's.  (Recent versions of Fedora, for example, only have Java 8 and later.)  When Oracle stopped public support for Java 6 and Java 7, the OpenJDK-based packages were deprecated.

However, if the builds exist you should be able to find them based on the information in the following OpenJDK page:

- [How to download and install prebuilt OpenJDK packages](https://openjdk.java.net/install/)

If you cannot find packages, and if you are willing to put in the necessary effort, it should be possible to download the relevant OpenJDK sources and create your own builds.

---

But my advice would be to upgrade your Java platform to Java 8, with a view to upgrading to Java 11 soon.  If you can't afford the effort and (potential) risk of upgrading, then you would be advised to pay for a Java support contract.